# Flutter 2.0 appbar back button disappeared if contains endDrawer

Tags: flutter

I just updated flutter to 2.0, and I realized all the back buttons disappeared if the appbar also conatains an endDrawer

[Appbar with endDrawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2jaf.png)

I tried to get rid of the endDrawer, the back button shows up, just not together with the endDrawer, it wasn't like that before the update, anybody knows how to solve this?

[Appbar without endDrawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Zbx.png)

my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Page1(),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
            child: TextButton(
          child: Text(
            'Page 1',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
          },
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: TextButton(
          child: Text(
            'Page 2',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        ),
      ),
      endDrawer: Drawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is current behavior in version 2.0, `if` condition also check `!hasEndDrawer` 
version 1.17

```
if (canPop)
          leading = useCloseButton ? const CloseButton() : const BackButton();
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/aee9e94c21009bfc6c08f442eacde06f001c25f9/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar.dart#L510

version 2.0

```
if (!hasEndDrawer && canPop)
      leading = useCloseButton ? const CloseButton() : const BackButton();
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ca2bef6ee915d943b5a160055b5065ec3391f19a/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar.dart#L793

You can add your own logic in `leading` 
code snippet

```
appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.maybeOf(context);
            final ModalRoute<dynamic> parentRoute = ModalRoute.of(context);
            final bool hasEndDrawer = scaffold?.hasEndDrawer ?? false;
            final bool canPop = parentRoute?.canPop ?? false;

            if (hasEndDrawer && canPop) {
              return BackButton();
            } else {
              return SizedBox.shrink();
            }
          },
        ),
        title: Text('Page 2'),
      ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Page1(),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
            child: TextButton(
          child: Text(
            'Page 1',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
          },
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.maybeOf(context);
            final ModalRoute<dynamic> parentRoute = ModalRoute.of(context);
            final bool hasEndDrawer = scaffold?.hasEndDrawer ?? false;
            final bool canPop = parentRoute?.canPop ?? false;

            if (hasEndDrawer && canPop) {
              return BackButton();
            } else {
              return SizedBox.shrink();
            }
          },
        ),
        title: Text('Page 2'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            child: Text(
              'Page 2',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      endDrawer: Drawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just add this to your AppBar/SliverAppBar

```
      leading: (ModalRoute.of(context)?.canPop ?? false) ? BackButton() : null,
```